# Linux variant of a sysprep answer file

Tags: linux, answer-file

I am installing a large number of Linux systems (RHEL5), from a preconfigured image. 
If I run sys-unconfig in that image before I distribute it, upon the first run of the imaged system, I get asked a lot of questions - hostname, IP, etc.

My question is how to pass the answers to those questions automatically, the way I would pass an answer file to a fresh sysprepped windows build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have RHEL here but on my FC11 in /etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit on line 705 I have the following:

```
if [ -f /.unconfigured ]; then
 # some code here to do some things
fi
```

So my first answer is unless you modify this file there is no way to automate this.  I will try to get a copy of the CENTOS version as is the same as RHEL and confirm that it is the same.

Granted RHEL may have done things different due to enterprise needs and I will confirm that.

Comment: Found the needed fields in RHEL5.3, thanks!